# adding session variables to itself

Tags: php, session-variables

I need to add amounts if a customer buys more than one product. how to add using session variables. I stored the amount as

```
$amount=$_POST['amount']
$_SESSION['amount']=$amount;
```

doing the following thing isnt solving the problem

```
$_SESSION['amount']+=$amount;
```

Comment: are you calling session start?

Comment: Is $_SESSION['amount'] what you expect it to be when you increment it?

Comment: Aren't you storing the products in the session as well? Your code seems to suggest that you're only storing one amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below code you are ovewriting the content of `$_SESSION['amount']` with the current value of `$_POST['amount']`:

```
$amount=$_POST['amount']
$_SESSION['amount']=$amount;
```

You should do something like this:

```
$currentAmount      = $_POST['amount']
$_SESSION['amount'] += $currentAmount;
```

Don't forget to check if you are calling `session_start()` at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm are you sure you have called the session_start() function at the beginning of your script.

If you have why don't you try breaking it up a bit.

```
$currentAmount = $_SESSION['amount']
$amount = $_POST['amount']
$_SESSION['amount'] = $currentAmount + $amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

not need to set session again and again.

```
$amount=$_POST['amount'];
//$_SESSION['amount']=$amount;
$_SESSION['amount']+=$amount;
```